# Need to add keydown event for ASP.net Text box and need to trigger a codebehind function using the keydown event

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

The page load event:

```
txtName.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "return doDataListBind()");`
```

Javascript:

```
function doDataListBind()
{
   document.getElementById("Button2").click();
}
```

Created a button and tried to trigger on-click event using JavaScript.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jQuery:

```
$( "#Button2" ).trigger( "click" );
```

Comment: Using the above code the button click is not triggered .Button is placed inside the content place holder... when i viewed the source from browser the id of the button is different like ctl00$content_Body$Button2..

Comment: Give me the full Javascript, please.

Comment: Try `$("#<%= Button2.ClientID %>").trigger("click");`